# make backup, each database in custom format, one unit

Tags: postgresql, database-backups

Maybe this thing will help, but I do not know how to arrange it:

```
select datname from pg_database where datallowconn and datname != 'template0'
```

This is how my script looks now:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
set -u
set -o pipefail


pathToConf=“$dir/conf_${currentDate}”
user=“postgres”
database=“db”


mkdir $pathToConf
cp /var/postgres/11/data/pg_hba.conf $pathToConf
cp /var/postgres/11/data/postgresql.conf $pathToConf



pg_dump -h 127.0.0.1 -d db -U ${user} -F c -f dump.tar.gz 
pg_dump -h 127.0.0.1 -U ${user} -F c -f dump.tar.gz template1
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. But one thing you should do either way is using proper double quotes (`"`) instead of those fancy ones (`“` and `”`). I can imagine the shell not liking the latter ones...

Comment: Yes, it is unclear what your script has to do with the list of databases.